# query optimization required

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
select oeh.header_id, oeh.order_number, oeh.ordered_date,oeh.sold_to_org_id as customer_id ,arc.customer_name as customer_name, oeh.INVOICE_TO_ORG_ID
, oel.attribute1 attribute1,  oel.attribute6 attribute6, oel.line_id, oel.line_number, oel.ordered_quantity, disc.wip_entity_id, disc.date_closed, disc.date_released, disc.date_released, disc.date_completed
from (APPS.oe_order_headers_all oeh INNER JOIN APPS.oe_order_lines_all oel
      ON oeh.org_id = oel.org_id -- not indexed
      and oeh.header_id = oel.header_id) -- both indexed
      INNER JOIN APPS.ar_customers arc 
      ON arc.customer_id = oeh.sold_to_org_id -- both indexed
      INNER JOIN XXCUS.xxgex_assemblies asm
      ON oel.line_id = asm.line_id -- BOTH INDEXED
      INNER JOIN APPS.wip_discrete_jobs disc
      ON disc.primary_item_id = asm.inventory_item_id -- both indexed
     where oel.link_to_line_id is null -- indexed
      and oeh.ordered_date > '31-DEC-2013'
      and disc.status_type NOT IN (1,7) -- Not Cancelled and Unreleased )
      and (
          ( disc.status_type in (3,4,6) )
          or
          (  disc.date_completed > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 400 
             and disc.status_type = 12 -- CLOSED 
          )
          )
    and disc.source_line_id is not null 
    and disc.source_code = 'WICDOL'
    and oeh.order_number between 1400000 and 1420050;
```

the columns in where clause are mostly indexed, my query returned 7 lines, and the cost in explain plan is 2990.

How can i use NOT EXIST instead of

> and disc.status_type NOT IN (1,7)

Any suggestions to optimize it?

Comment: Is not the *disc.status_type NOT IN (1,7)* futile? the next condition supposes type in 3,4,6 or type=12

Comment: @StanislavL these are the requirements: where disc.status_type NOT IN (1,7) -- Not Cancelled and Unreleased )
      and (
             ( disc.status_type in (3,4,6) )
              or
             (  disc.date_completed > TRUNC(SYSDATE) - 400 and disc.status_type = 12 -- CLOSED 
             )
          )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions to optimize your query:

1. Add Index on APPS.oe_order_headers_all.org_id (only this column in index)
2. Add Index on APPS.wip_discrete_jobs.status_type (only this column in index)
3. Move `and disc.status_type NOT IN (1,7)` to be the first condition in the where clause.

I am not sure that NOT EXISTS would be the correct choice here.

Comment: I have 2 indexes on APPS.wip_discrete_jobs.status_type, what will be the effect if there are 2 indexes on 1 column?

Comment: If both indexes are only on the 1 column, you can drop one of them. Otherwise Oracle will choose the better one to use depending on your query.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your access path either disc.source_code or oeh.order_number, whichever is more selective. Hope one of them is indexed. Also you can add index on org_id, if its more selective than header_id. As @StanislavL said, you can remove disc.status_type NOT IN (1,7).